# iOS 11 20 points gap over tableview in UITableViewController with static cells

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, xcode9

[image]

I have been using a UITableViewController in my app. It worked fine in iOS 10.x.x but I recently upgraded my Xcode and iOS to (Xcode 9 and iOS 11). Then the my app is having this UI issue. It will show a 20 points gap above the UITableView in a UITableViewController with static cells. Anyone having same problem and found the solution for this?

Comment: This is known as safe area, this area is guide to manage your app for ios11 apps so your UI not end up in mess in iphone8 and iPhonex specially.

Comment: So I played with a different properties in Controller and TableView, this will go if I disable the scroll in tableview. but this is not the solution since I want my tableview to scroll. So how do we cope with this layout issue?

Comment: from the problem you have describe i don't think its the safe area, you might want to check height of header of UITableview

Comment: Header Height is set to 1. Estimate 0.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the new property introduced in iOS 11. Try the following:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[chengsam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3378821/chengsam)'s answer works perfectly to solve this problem.

If you want to accomplish the iOS 11 part in Interface Builder, you can do so. It's available in the Size Selector in the Utilities View.

[image: IB Contents Inset property]